# Detect end dragging in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` added to it's view.

I'd like to detect if the user has **stopped** dragging down on the `tableView`.

I understand there is a `tableView.isDragging` prop that will tell me if the table is currently dragging. However should this prop be true, I'd like to delay an action until they have stopped.

As such I was hoping I could use something like `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` but I do not believe `UIViewController` has access to this as it is not a subclass of a scroll view.

Is there anyway I can detect this action?

Comment: “scrollViewDidEndDecelerating but I do not believe UIViewController has access to this“ well it does. UITableView Is a scroll view so just give it a delegate.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, I appreciate you clarifying this for me, I am learning everyday and you have helped tremendously

Comment: Have you tried adding a gesture recognizer to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the table view has a delegate (UITableViewDelegate). The table view is also a scroll view and that delegate is also its scroll view delegate (UIScrollViewDelegate). So implement `didEnd` there.